# Height in UITableviewcell

Tags: ios, uitableview, heightforrowatindexpath

I have custom tableviewcell in my tableview.

I can set height of that cell in this method.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{ }
```

But, is it possible to dynamically change height in uitableviewcell file (E.g. FlightDetailCell.m)

Comment: Why not just change it inside that method?

Comment: It is because I did some calculation in FlightDetailCell.m. If not, I need to use delegate back to tableview and reload tableview.

Comment: When is the calculation done in FlightDetailCell.m?

Comment: amm..Some data is pass from tableview controller and if there is some value, I make it longer. If not, I make it shorter. I can check in tableviewcontroller also but it is like I will be checking again in FlightDetailCell.m.

Comment: Hmm. Personally, my advice would probably be to do just do the calculations in your table view controller if possible, but I'm sure there are other alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but you must call  `- (void)[reloadData];` to update the table view.

See [reloadData](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadData)

Comment: in FlightDetailCell.m? I can't call [self reloadData] there.

Comment: @KhantThuLinn: No, you'd have to call it from your viewController. You can achieve this through a delegate, callback, or notification (the latests would be my favorite)

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to calculate the height of the cell in `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;` when ever you reload above method will be called inorder to set the updated heigh. That time you need to pass the updated dynamic hight.

Answer (score 1):

you can do that using custom cell delegate:

to try my example:

- create new project with single view controller named `ViewController`
- paste code from example into .m file
- create custom cell named `TableViewCell`
- paste code into .h and .m files
- run and press on the cell. its height will change =)

hope it helps!

**example:**

**implementation of view controller with table view:**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "TableViewCell.h"

@interface ViewController ()<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, TableViewCellDelegate>
{
    UITableView* m_tableView;
    NSMutableArray* m_arrayOfCellHeight;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

#define kCellCount 3
#define kDefaultCellHeight 44
#define kCellIdentifier @"kCellIdentifier"

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    m_tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, 320, 300)];
    m_tableView.delegate = self;
    m_tableView.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:m_tableView];

    m_arrayOfCellHeight = [NSMutableArray new];

    for (int i = 0; i < kCellCount; i++)
        [m_arrayOfCellHeight addObject:@(kDefaultCellHeight)];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [m_arrayOfCellHeight[indexPath.row] floatValue];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 3;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TableViewCell* _cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];
    if (!_cell)
    {
        _cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];
    }
    _cell.textLabel.text = @"press me";
    _cell.delegate = self;
    return _cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [(TableViewCell*)[m_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] changeHeight];
}

- (void)cell:(TableViewCell *)cell didChangeHeight:(CGFloat)height
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [m_tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    m_arrayOfCellHeight[indexPath.row] = @(height);
    [m_tableView beginUpdates];
    [m_tableView endUpdates];
}

@end
```

**cell interface:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol TableViewCellDelegate;
@interface TableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<TableViewCellDelegate> delegate;
- (void) changeHeight;

@end

@protocol TableViewCellDelegate <NSObject>

- (void) cell:(TableViewCell*)cell didChangeHeight:(CGFloat)height;

@end
```

**implementation of cell:**

```
@implementation TableViewCell

- (void) changeHeight
{
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(cell:didChangeHeight:)])
    {
        CGFloat _float = rand()%70 + 30;
        [self.delegate cell:self didChangeHeight:_float];
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

in iOS8 Self-Sizing Cells feature has been introduced. I have provided a tutorial about it also explained what happens underhood. It is pretty simple and will boost your development time.

http://kemal.co/index.php/2014/07/an-example-of-self-sizing-cells-introduced-in-ios8/

Comment: This link is dead. Please include the relevant information from the linked page in the future.